# jQuery add class name or ID +1 and -1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, class

As you can read in the title, it's about any class or ID to increase by 1. For example: I have 3 IDs they calles id1, id2 and id3. id1 is visible but the other two are hidden. So now I want by clicking on a button that id1 is no longer visible, but is visible for id2. After clicking on next when the last id is visible it have to turn back to first.
And I want also by clicking on another button for example that id2 is not longer visible, but visible for id1 again.

**My current jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var size_ini = 1;
    var size_increase = size_ini++;        
    $("#next").click(function() {
        $("#id" + size_increase).css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

My HTML code:

```
<div>
    <p id="id1">first</p>
    <p id="id2" style="display: none;">second</p>
    <p id="id3" style="display: none;">third</p>
</div>
<button id="prev">prev</button>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

*So my question is, what do i wrong or what have i to do else to do it right.*

Comment: You keep resetting your `size_ini` var to `1` every time the click function is called, so it's basically acting like a constant. YOu need to define it as a global variable **OUTSIDE** of the function so it only initializes once.

Comment: thank u, but doesnt fix my problem

Comment: Consider using data attributes such as `data-my-number="1"`

Comment: @MarcB This is not true. The function in which size_ini is declared is called only once, right after the creation of the document.

Comment: @abl: OP editted the code to move the initialization out of the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('$("#next").click()', 10000);
    var size = 1;
    $("#next").click(function() {
        $("#id" + size).hide();
        if(size === 3) {
            size = 1;
        }
        else {
            size++;
        }
        $("#id" + size).show();
    });
    $("#prev").click(function() {
        $("#id" + size).hide();
        if(size === 1) {
            size = 3;
        }
        else {
            size--;
        }
        $("#id" + size).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: when clicking prev it should go back

Comment: can u add another function :/ that ever 10 sec. goes to the heigher id.

Comment: Done. Any more changes should be asked as a new question.

Comment: I have answered your question, and more. Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLm7Q/1/

you should define size_ini globally. and use a class for all objects so you can hide them together. also you can use show/hide methods instead of changing css. this one also goes to 1 after 3 and 3 after 1. and this will do it every 10 seconds. js code:

```
var size_ini = 1;
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var myVar = setInterval('$("#next").click()',10000)  
    $("#next").click(function() {
        clearInterval(myVar);
        setInterval('$("#next").click()',10000)  
        if(size_ini < 3)
        size_ini++;
        else
        size_ini = 1
        $(".sample").hide();
        $("#id" + size_ini).show();
    });
    $("#prev").click(function() {
        clearInterval(myVar);
        setInterval('$("#prev").click()',10000)      
        if(size_ini > 1)
        size_ini--;
        else        
        size_ini = 3;
        $(".sample").hide();
        $("#id" + size_ini).show();
    });    
});
```

and the html:

```
<div>
    <p class='sample' id="id1">first</p>
    <p class='sample' id="id2" style="display: none;">second</p>
    <p class='sample' id="id3" style="display: none;">third</p>
</div>
<button id="prev">prev</button>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

Comment: volkan bir de bi yapsan ki de her 10 saniyede bir kere atlasin :)

Comment: did it. english please ;)

Comment: there is a little problem, the countdown of 10 sec. starts when the site is loaded. when i click next or prev the countdown should start new.

Comment: it will now start over whenever you click prev/next buttons